# Setting object as value to attr() method in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using `$.data()` function to set the size of a div:

```
function init() {
    comp = $("#center");
    comp.data('image', {
        dimensions : {
            width : comp.width(),
            height : comp.height(),
            x0 : comp.position().left,
            y0 : comp.position().top,           
        }
    });
}
```

I'm retrieving the value like:

```
var image = comp.data('image');
alert(image.dimensions.x1);
```

The code is fine and it's working too. I would like to know if it is possible to do via `$.attr()` function and which way would be better.

Comment: Have you tried? It's obviously not possible due to the fact that attributes can only be strings.

Comment: But jQuery cache can contain non-string values, so it's not that obvious.

Answer (score 1):

you can handle this easily like that:

```
var values = {width: '100px', height: '100px'};
$('#id-of-your-img').css(values);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try a attr("style", ""), but I would prefer to use css() for CSS manipulation. See here: http://api.jquery.com/css/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a example where someone added a function to create a similar behaviour with some extra features.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rodneyrehm/XV33m/)

```
// dispatch to data() and attr()
$.fn.dataAttr = function(key, value) {
    var $this = this,
        ret = this.data(key, value);

    if (typeof key == "object") {
        $.each(key, function(key, value) {
            $this.attr("data-" + jQuery.uncamelCase(key), typeof value in {string:1, number:1} ? value : '~defined~');
        });
    } else if (value !== undefined) {
        $this.attr("data-" + jQuery.uncamelCase(key), typeof value in {string:1, number:1} ? value : '~defined~');
    }

    return ret;
};
```